# Return an array of vowels used within a string

Tags: arrays, ruby, block

I am struggling with a ruby challenge the task is

Write a method that will take a string and
return an array of vowels used in that string.

Example:
count_vowels("The quick brown fox") should return ["e","u","i","o","o"]

count_vowels("Hello World") should return ["e","o","o"]

so far i have tried experimenting with blocks and other array methods like

```rb
def vowels(string)
 string_array = string.chars
  vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
  p string_array & vowels

end
```

also

```rb
def vowels (string)
  # Your code here
  arr =(string).downcase.chars
    new =[]
  values = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
arr. { |words| values.include?(words.each) }
    end
```

Comment: ...What have you tried?

Comment: sorry have edited

Comment: `vowels = %w[a e i o u].to_set; 'The quick brown fox'.chars.select { |ch| vowels.include? ch }`

Comment: Tip: [`scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-scan).

Comment: The second example is broken (`arr. ...`).

Comment: @AlexLittle : Why do you want to call the method _**count**vowels_, when there is no counting to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code piece should help you

## Edited:-

```
def count_vowels(word)
   word.downcase.chars.select{|c|  %[a,e,i,o,u].include?(c)}
end
```

Comment: Works, but here `select` would be a cleaner approach.

Comment: Answer is modified, have a look now

Comment: This works thanks for you help i see what you have done here

Answer (score 3):

For academic purposes, here's another approach:

```
def vowels(str)
  # Delete all the non-vowel characters from the string and return the remaining characters
  str.downcase.tr('^aeiou', '').chars
end

vowels("The quick brown fox")
# => ["e", "u", "i", "o", "o"]
vowels("Hello World")
# => ["e", "o", "o"]
```

This, coincidentally, is based on an example in the [`String#tr`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-tr) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid splitting the string into an array of chars first by using [`String.scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-scan) with a regexp.

```
string = "The quick brown fox"
string.scan(/(a|e|i|o|u)/i).flatten
#=> ["e", "u", "i", "o", "o"]

string = "Hello World"
string.scan(/(a|e|i|o|u)/i).flatten
#=> ["e", "o", "o"]
```

The `i` at the end makes the regexp case-insensitive.

It probably depends on the size of the string if it is faster to build a regexp and scan the string in one go or to split the string into an array first and then iterate over all chars and compare them against another array.